# Cannot compile using -std flag with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, cygwin

I'm running Windows 7 with cygwin installed and trying to have a play around with some of the newer C++ features.  I'm aware that in order to enable these features I have to pass g++ the -std=c++0x flag, however that gives me the following error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

The command line I'm issueing that gives rise to that error is:

```
g++-3 hello.cpp -std=c++0x -o hello
```

The reason for the g++-3 is because windows has trouble with the symbolic link. I've used g++ in the cygwin terminal and the result is the same anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output when you type `g++-3 --version`

Comment: cygwin usually has pretty out-of-date versions of gcc/g++.

Comment: @PaulR: Maybe, but not THAT out of date.  Mine has g++-4.5.3, and I haven't even done cygwin-setup in a while.

Comment: @Anti-Distinctlyminty if you want to do yourself a favour, get VirtualBox, install Ubuntu on it and use Linux, i would argue that you will have an easier life but the full fledged Linux experience.

Comment: If it's still not working try -std=c++11

Comment: @GWW: output from g++-3 version is
g++-3 (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
Coming from using Visual Studio, the compilers choices and options are a bit overwhelming :)

Comment: @larsmans: see above comment.

Comment: Here's the output from the compiler I managed to get working after poking around in the cygwin bin folder:
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.5.3)`

Comment: @OliverStutz: I have Linux Mint installed, however, I need to develop code that will be compiled on OS X and Windows. As I work on Windows most of the time I'm using gcc to 1. Try out simple examples of C++11 features and 2. Keep myself ticking over with compiling using gcc. 
Oh, the joy of cross platform development :)

Comment: @Chris: -std=c++11 alas, does not work. It's an unrecognised flag.

Comment: @oldrinb: Is MinGW not part of the Cygwin installation? Forgive me if that's a stupid question, as I stated a few posts above, it's a little confusing coming from Visual Studio to gcc with all it's versions and packages.

Comment: @Anti-Distinctlyminty cygwin and MinGW are pretty independent of one another... they serve different purposes last I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using a version of GCC which supports C++ 2011 features.

[This page has a list of compilers and which features each one supports](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). If I were you, I'd try to use GCC 4.7 if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies & sorry for the delay. I wasn't notified of them :/
Anyway, I managed to compile it using 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++0x -static-libstdc++ hello.cpp -o hello

Comment: I switched to c++ 4.7 in mingw from cygwin. So now I just use
`c++ -std=c++11 hello.cpp -o hello` and all is well :)
NB: only 32 bit, I couldn't find how to get the 64 bit mingw.